# Draw custom bars in a Highcharts bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to draw custom bars with rounded corners to get lozenge shaped bars. There's also a requirement to overlay icons on or near some bars.

How can I override or access the rendering code for bars?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this opption is not avaiable in highcharts, but you can request your suggestions in our uservoice system http://highcharts.uservoice.com

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, you don't need to over ride any rendering:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nHGRr/3/

```
plotOptions:{
        series: {
            borderRadius:10      
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe we have fluid requirements for custom bar rendering which may include other customisations. Good tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

Include the following plugin.

> plotOptions:{
>         series: {
>                borderRadiusTopLeft: 5,
>                borderRadiusTopRight: 5
>           }
>       }